# Vertically docking Tools toolbar to left of map and right of TOC in ArcMap 10.x?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, ux

In general, I really like the docking environment in ArcGIS 10.  As I was showing off ArcGIS 10 to some of my end-users, I couldn't get the toolbar docked to the left of the map and to the right of the table of contents (TOC). Am I missing something here?  I want to configure like ArcMap 9.3.1:

[image]

I think as a workaround, end users can dock the toolbar to the left of the TOC, and auto-hide the TOC(personally, I will do this).  Or they can dock the TOC to the right of the map (and maybe also auto hide the TOC).

---

To quote @MattWilkie:

> Please vote for ArcMap to bring back vertical toolbar docking, next to
>   table of contents at
>   http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008GlOAAU

Comment: +1, I use this layout when working on a "wide-screen" style monitor to maximise vertical screen space.

Comment: I really like the docking feature of the Arc Toolbox in 9.3.1 + the tabs below it where you can enter a command or tool name in Search & quickly find it. I miss this in 10. Why was this feature changed & not improved on? Can we see it back in 10?

Comment: Please vote for Arcmap to bring back vertical toolbar docking, next to table of contents at http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008GlOAAU

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a thread at the ESRI Forums on the issue: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/166-Beta-10-Docking-Tools-toolbar-Vertically?highlight=dock+toolbars+vertically

Currently, the toolbar cannot dock between the Table of Contents and map. The closest thing is that the tools can be docked vertically to the left of the TOC.

For now, unless someone codes a very clever workaround, you can contact ESRI support for updates on the issue; refer to bug number NIM050280.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question/complaint posted on Twitter and in other forums. I don't think it's possible to do what you want right now. Judging by the number of users who want it, I'd guess it'll be included in the next version.

Answer (score -1):

click and drag the toolbox and/or any floated windows to desired position (could be left or right) automatically the arrow direction to desired position appear, then double click on the floated windows.. the window menu will attached on the arcview side panel bar...

Comment: This does not sound right to me.  Would you be able to describe your precise steps in more detail, please?

Answer (score -2):

Docking Table of Contents in ArcGIS 10.1 can be done by double clicking on the 'table of contents' text or moving the floating window to anyone of the 'docking' icons that show up when trying to move the  floating window.  If you dock by moving the window your cursor must move on top of the blue docking icon.

Comment: OP was asking about docking a toolbar to the right of TOC; not about how to dock the TOC itself. Note the picture.